# Can I download music files that I own to another computer from Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I uploaded my music to Ubuntu One.  Can I download it as files to another computer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If it's another Ubuntu computer then log into Ubuntu One on there and they should sync. If it's windows/mac then go to the [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) online and download from there!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. You can login to Ubuntu One's web interface from most any computer and download your files. Also, you can make the files public and share them with others by giving them the public link.

Make sure you read the Ubuntu One terms of service, and also be careful you aren't violating any copyright laws by redistributing music you don't have the rights to. Those are the only limitations really, as there is no technical barrier for what you want to do.